# Why Visual Studio 2010 webform project not generates Events?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, webforms

I have Created an webform project(not website). on the default page i have added one button and change its id to btnClickMe and try to write click button event. I clicked it twice to generate the event but it couldn't redidrect me to aspx.cs file. then i tried it from the properties->events panel but again the event couldn't generate. Then I create new website and on default page i added a button and clicked it to generate its working... but in webform project its not working.

What is the reason behind it?

Comment: You clicked it in design view, right?

Comment: Yes I have clicked it in design view and then on the properties panel after selecting the button... i restarted the visual studio but again its not generating the event

Comment: Can we see the markup?

Comment: Thanks dear I have just restarted my pc and try it and it now working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create an event you must double click the button from the design view so Visual Studio can prepare the background operations to create that event. Simply writing the same commands on .cs side will not create the event and will not trigger the codes you write in between. If it still doesn't work, restart your computer to make the program run properly.

Comment: i have double click that but it doesn't generate the event

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to add the code yourself; design view is noted for bugs and inconsistencies:

```
protected void btnClickMe(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that `AutoEventWireup="true"` exists in your `Page` directive, something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```